# Automatic NSEncoding detection

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, nsdata

On my program I receive an NSData that has a string sometimes encoded in UTF8, other times in Latin1. Is there a way to automatically detect which encoding is being used?
I tried writing it to a file so I could use `stringWithContentsOfFile:usedEncoding:error:` but it always responds with UTF8.

```
[receivedData writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
NSError *error = nil;
Debug(@"Write returned error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
NSStringEncoding enc;
NSString *content=[NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path usedEncoding:&enc error:&error];
```

Maybe I'm not understanding correctly how I should approach the problem but from what I've read `stringWithContentsOfFile:usedEncoding:error:` should be the way to go. Any suggestions on what I'm doing wrong or how to approach this?

Answer (score 0):

You can get encoding from the response. (e.g. NSURLResponse, NSHTTPURLResponse...)

```
    NSStringEncoding stringEncoding = NSUTF8StringEncoding;
    if (response.textEncodingName) {
        CFStringEncoding encoding = CFStringConvertIANACharSetNameToEncoding((CFStringRef)response.textEncodingName);
        if (encoding != kCFStringEncodingInvalidId) {
            stringEncoding = CFStringConvertEncodingToNSStringEncoding(encoding);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a good chance that your text actually only contains ASCII characters, so it cannot be distinguished whether the encoding used was UTF-8 or some latin encoding. It's most likely that you will be told "it's UTF-8" in that case.

To test this properly, you have to convince the server to send something like ÄÖÜ using a latin encoding.

(It's also quite difficult to guess which encoding was used if it wasn't UTF-8, since usually many 8 bit encodings could have been valid).